# How do I check if any special characters exists in a string?

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where the string shouldn't contain anything apart from letters.

eg if sring value is - ****apexrest/api/abc/someGarbage*$/KLK9K''L***

The requirement is strictly to check the presence of any special character or number and not to replace it and make it a valid string.

How can I check it in apex ?

Comment: if valid letters include accented letters or letters in Cyrillic, etc, see String class `isAlpha()`

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex can do this:

```
String stringToMatch = requestURI.removeStart('/apexrest/api/abc/');
Pattern specialCharPattern = Pattern.compile('[^a-zA-Z]');
Matcher patternMatcher = specialCharPattern.matcher(stringToMatch);
Boolean hasSpecialChars = patternMatcher.find();
```

Comment: You are awesome !